# Thrown exceptions while deploying EJB Module with Eclipse using Glassfish 3.1

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish, ejb

My problem is about eclipse and glassfish 3.1

I create simple EJB Project using Eclipse wizard; choose runtime server (glassfish 3.1, downaload all needed files by Eclipse) and all is ok. After i choose "Run -> Run on server" i get error while deploying.

I tryed to start server before making new ejb module and server sarted correctly, after ejb module is created it's not synchronizing.. I am also sure that right server instance was choosen and there is no PORT conflict.

EJB module is fine for sure, before I did it with Eclipse i was working with Netbeans and all was fine - i am using different instances of glassfish for eclipse and netbenas, so it's not a reason of my problem.

Here is server log: http://pastebin.com/RDwNAzs8
I put it to pastebin, becouse of it huge content.

Greetings!

Comment: Is this class, "com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper" used anywhere in your EAR/WAR? file?

Comment: No, it's simple project with Stateless Bean, Java class. There is nothing special in it, simple construction. I am sure it's fine, because I have been already using it with Netbeans. Dunno meaby any .xml file config might be a problem ?

Comment: I think you're going to need to post your glassfish version, which jdk glassfish is using, and your ejb code, how you installed glassfish, and tell us "how" you are deploying your ejb.

EJBs are dead simple. Take a class, toss an annotation on it, done. Something is probably wrong with the method you're pushing it out to the server.

Comment: It looks like the `security.jar` is somehow missing. Can you verify that it is present in `GLASSFISH_ROOT/glassfish/modules`?

Comment: @unwichtich : It's right there: bash-4.2$ ls
bin  glassfish  javadb  mq  pkg
bash-4.2$ find ./ -name security.jar
./glassfish/modules/security.jar
bash-4.2$

Comment: @exabrial : Ihave already writen GF version, it was 3.1. What about JDK ? While configuring GF i was able to choose "default jre" and "java", "java" path was /usr/lib64/java so i supouse it was JRE not JDK. What JDK is for glassfish, may it be reason of it's warning ? That step i have chosen "java".